# How to change Woo Commerce page in wordpress

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to get rid of the information displayed above the actual check out page. It shows me Welcome Admin, and contact numbers and email. I want to change those details.
The checkout page in wordpress only shows a shortcode for [woocommercepage_checkout], which css should i go to ?

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure it isn't coming from your theme? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: It can be from your theme or from WooCommerce. In such situations, I just do a string search in my CSS files and see where is that text coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hook to which you can add your custom css.(A helpful like for this would be [WP_ENQUEUE_STYLE](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style))

In the hook function you can register and enqueue your custom css file. In order to ensure that your custom CSS won't desrupte other page's styling write your enqueuing line in a conditions like is is_checkout().

All this code you need to add in your theme's functions.php or you can add this in your custom plugin.

Later all styling part can be handled in the css file which you register and enqueue.

This way you can Elegantly deal with the styling in a WordPress way.